# What would a nectarivorous animal do with waste it can't expel?

Tags: xenobiology, food

I'm reading about these species of aliens that survive solely off of nectar, honey, sugar, and sugar-based products. It's not mentioned whether or not they drink water, but it is mentioned they genetically modified themselves to be lacking in "waste disposal." How could these aliens make the most out of their food source? What could they do with the extra materials they may not digest? Is this even possible at all?

Comment: Is this a worldbuilding question, or is it about an existing world? If it's about an existing world, it may get closed. Edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm basically "stealing" the most basic anatomy ideas of it, so no, not necessarily an existing world.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Waste is gas.**

Does that count?  A car does not pee or poo, because it exhales its water as vapor and CO2 as the gas.  If your aliens were fueling themselves with carbs as a car is fueled with gas, maybe the waste is all gaseous metabolic waste.

2. **It grows.**

A crystal does not excrete as it takes in soluble "nutrient".  Those materials are added to the crystal, which grows with time.  If your aliens encounter or produce some nongaseous material it cannot exhale, this material is incorporated into the alien's body.

Answer (score 1):

## Deposition in skin/carapace:

Waste is deposited in either skin or a carapace. As the skin flakes or a carapace is shed, the waste materials are carried away with it. So whatever outer coating your aliens have, it is likely something that grows and is at least periodically shed. A high concentration of unpleasant waste in the outer surface might be a defensive mechanism as well to make the species unpalatable to predators at some point in evolution.

Liquid wastes can be carried off in a similar manner as sweat. As it is, [humans sweat urea](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12817713/) and uric acid. The liquid portions evaporate off or are washed away, while the solid portions deposit on the skin and are shed or washed away with it.